# Unknown column 'modules.modules_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

here is the sql codes

```
SELECT
roles.role_id,
usertype_module.role_id,
usertype_module.viewable,
usertype_module.editable,
usertype_module.createable,
modules.modules_id,
usertype_module.modules_id,
modules.modules,
roles.role_name
FROM
modules ,
roles
INNER JOIN usertype_module ON roles.role_id = usertype_module.role_id AND usertype_module.modules_id = modules.modules_id
```

and this error showed 
Unknown column 'modules.modules_id' in 'on clause'

pls help me thanks

Comment: Your query is referring to a column that doesn't exist.  Without information about the structure of your tables, we can't help you further.

Comment: Why use an implicit JOIN on roles (without any JOIN conditions) and then an explicit JOIN on usertype_module?  Pick one style of defining JOINs (hopefully explicitly) and stick with it.  Doing both creates confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a mistake in the query. Is this what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT
roles.role_id,
usertype_module.role_id,
usertype_module.viewable,
usertype_module.editable,
usertype_module.createable,
modules.modules_id,
usertype_module.modules_id,
modules.modules,
roles.role_name
FROM
roles
INNER JOIN usertype_module ON roles.role_id = usertype_module.role_id 
INNER JOIN modules ON usertype_module.modules_id = modules.modules_id
```